# Django, I deleted AnonymousUser, how to restore

Tags: django, database

(amazing, I have not found such a question yet!)

I deleted part of my users in the db, and accidentally also the `AnonymousUser`-instance. 
How do I restore him? (well... him or her, for the sake of political correctness :-P)

I do need an instance of him in the db, right? (so far, by quickly browsing my site, I have not run into issues). What would be the problems without him, by the way?

But there is no `AnonymousUser.objects`-manager to create one. And `save()` is not implemeted anyway, like [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object) say. So do I drop the users table and migrate? Will it help and/or can I proceed differently?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Anonymous user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object) is an instance of `django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser` and is created on the fly when the auth backend does not found any authenticated user in session and **it is not stored in the database**, hence `save` is not implemented on this and `id` is always None as the doc states.

**Update after comment**

`django-userena` uses [django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian) to manage per object permissions, and `django-guardian` will create this user [automatically](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian/blob/ccc88dadddba3900b8b18ce83eb6b24e05efef96/guardian/management/__init__.py#L45) listening to `signals.post_migrate` signal. So simply run migrate command and you should have your so called anonymous user back (This is not an instance of `django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser` it is an actual user instance of your user model).

You can disable this behavior altogether depending on your needs, check `django-guardian` [docs](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#anonymous-user-name).

Comment: ...but there was an AnonymousUser shown in my list of users before, and now it's not! aaah, maybe some package (userena?) created a normal user and called him AnonymousUser? - which would be very misleading, not at all pythonic

Comment: yeah, you are right! Thank you for the explanation. Very misleading of django-guardian. I'll propose to rename the default to not be exactly equal to the wrong class name. I would have thought of this myself in that case.